# How to extract labels from json?

Tags: json, react-native, label

I have this json:

```
"client":{
  "datas": {
       "number1": 14,
       "number2": 2,
       "number3": 1,
       "city": [
          "paris",
          "tokyo",
          "nyc",
          "london"
       ]
    },
}
```

I want to extract label/value peers for the "number" labels but not for the array like that:

```
number 1 : 14
number 2 : 2
numer 3 : 1
paris,
tokyo,
nyc,
london
```

Edit: 
I tried this loop:

```
    for (i  in datas) 
    {  newDatas = clents.datas[i]; }
```

I get :

```
14
2
1
Array [
 "paris",
 "tokyo",
 "nyc",
 "london", ]
```

Comment: Simply loop through each of the fields in the map and test whether the associated value is of type "array."  Ignore these fields.

Comment: I tried this loop:    
        for (i  in datas) 
        {  newDatas = clents.datas[i]; }
        
I get : 
14
2
1
Array [
"paris",
"tokyo",
"nyc",
"london", ]